# How to loop comma separated values within for loop?

Tags: jquery, arrays

My ajax script below, takes json_encoded values from php script. The PHP script contains single value and also arrays. For single values I've no issue as I use the first loop to loop through them. For array values, I've no idea on how to loop through.

> As far as i know, comma separated values can be put into array by
>   split(',').But for my case, it doesn't output anything. Where's my
>   mistake in the second for loop?

My full script:

```
 $("#receipt").on("click",function()
 {
     var ele = $(".header_tbl tbody tr").children().length;

     if(ele !=0)
     {
        $("#after_cash_cart_form").submit(function(){
                var data = {
                  "action": "test"
                };
                data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);

                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType: "json",
                  url: "submit_cart.php",
                  data: data,
                  success: function(data) {

                     for(var i=0;i < data.length; i++)
                     {
                         //alert(data[i].price.length);//outputs '3'
                         //data[i].price; //outputs 120,200,150
                         var array = data[i].price.split(",");

                         for (var j=0;j < array.length; j++)
                         {
                             alert(array[j]);//doesn't output anything
                         }

                     }

                  }

                });
                return false;
       });
     }else
     {
       alert("Your cart is empty.");
     }
 });
```

Comment: Can you please share the value of data within AJAX. edit: vvv that's why I asked that ;)

Comment: If `data[i].price` outputs `120,200,150`, then `data[i].price.length` should not be `2`.

Comment: @Ivar, sorry it should be 3, its a typo

Comment: is `.price` an array or a string?

Comment: @eithedog, console.log(data) outputs [object].

Comment: @Ivar, data[i].price is a string where the values like: 120,200,150. But I'm trying to make it into array via the nested loop.

Comment: I'm confused, you can't split an array

Comment: If you have something that outputs `120, 200, 150` in an alert, and it's length is `3`, it's an array

Comment: No, data[i].price is a string.

Comment: Not according to what you've posted, but just do `typeof data[i].price` to find out

Comment: @adeneo, typeof says object

Comment: And arrays are objects, so you have an array

Comment: @adeneo, oh thanks for that! But how do I access each item in that array via for loop?

Comment: for (var j=0;j < data[i].price.length; j++){alert(array[j]); }  This doesn't output anyting

Comment: `$.each(data[i].price, function(j, price) { alert(price) });`

Comment: `for (var j=0;j < data[i].price.length; j++){alert(array[j]); }`-> Maybe you should alert `data[i].price[j]`.

Answer (score 1):

`data[i].price` is already an array, so you don't need to `split(",")` it.

Instead of

```
var array = data[i].price.split(",");
```

just use

```
var array = data[i].price;
```

and then the rest of your code should work.